# provide close button to div while creation in Dojo

Tags: dojo

I am creating a div dynamically.

```
var item = domConstruct.create("div", null, test);
item.innerHTML = "New Div";
```

On creation I am getting a div with label "New Div". I want the user to add the name to div and a close button so that they can delete the div after creation.
[Image of div with edit and delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn11c.png)

Any help on this will be great.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: if (domClass.contains(evt.target, "esriAddBookmark")) {
                    var bmTable = _bookmark.Bookmarks;
                    var extent= _bookmark.sceneview.extent.xmin + ',' + _bookmark.sceneview.extent.ymin + ',' + _bookmark.sceneview.extent.xmax + ',' + _bookmark.sceneview.extent.ymax + ',' + _bookmark.sceneview.extent.spatialReference.wkid;
                    var item = domConstruct.create("div", null, bmTable);
                    item.innerHTML = "New Bookmark";

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view defining such div with all controls as templated widget would be a better approach. Instead of domConstruct you'll have to create new instance of your templated widget. 
Inside of widget you'll be able to attach event to close button to delete your div. Like this:

**MyDiv.js**

```
    define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!MyDiv.html"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    template
) {
    return declare("MyDiv", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        deleteDiv: function () {
            //do some stuff
            this.destroy(); //destroy widget and its dom node

        }
    });
});
```

MyDiv.html may look like this:

```
<div>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span data-dojo-attach-event="click: deleteDiv">Close Me</span>
</div>
```

Here link to dojo docs on this topic:
[_TemplatedMixin](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html)